# The Remez Algorithm

Tags: optimization, approximation

The Remez algorithm is a well-known iterative routine to approximate a function by a polynomial in the minimax norm. But, as Nick Trefethen [1] says about it:

> Most of these [implementations] go back many years and in fact, most of them do not solve the general best approximation problem as posed above but variants involving discrete variables or digital filtering. One can find a few other computer programs in circulation, but overall, it seems that there is no widely-used program at present for computing best approximations.

One can compute the minimax solution also by applying least-squares or convex optimization, for example using Matlab and the free CVX toolbox applied to the Runge function on [-1, 1]:

```
m = 101; n = 11;            % 101 points, polynomial of degree 10
xi = linspace(-1, 1, m);    % equidistant points in [-1, 1]
ri = 1 ./ (1+(5*xi).^2);    % Runge function

tic                         % p is the polynomial of degree (n-1)
cvx_begin                   % minimize the distance in all points
    variable p(n);
    minimize( max(abs(polyval(p, xi) - ri)) );
cvx_end
toc                         % 0.17 sec for Matlab, CVX and SeDuMi
```

The approximation with Chebyshev polynomials has a minimax norm of `0.1090` while this approach here reaches a minimum of `0.0654`, the same value that gets computed with the Remez algorithm in the Matlab `chebfun` toolbox.

Is there any advantage in applying the more complicated Remez algorithm if you can compute the minimax solution faster and more accurate with an optimization solver? Are there any reports/articles comparing these two approaches on some difficult problems or test cases?

--
[1] R. Pachon and L. N. Trefethen. BIT Numerical Mathematics (2008) Vol. 46.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "right" answer strongly depends on what you need your approximant for. Do you really need the best approximation for some error bound? Or just a good approximation? Or just a good approximation in the minmax sense?

Nick Trefethen recently gave a [nice example](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/mythspaper.pdf) where Remez approximation is a bad idea since it minimizes the maximum error irrespective of the average error over the entire interval, which may not be what you want. Of course, the maximum error may be large, but this is bounded for smooth functions.

**Update**

Following the discussion in the comments below, I downloaded the CVX Toolbox and did a direct comparison with the Chebfun Remez algorithm (disclaimer: I am part of the Chebfun development team):

```
% Do the convex optimization bit.
m = 101; n = 11;            % 101 points, polynomial of degree 10
xi = linspace(-1, 1, m);    % equidistant points in [-1, 1]
ri = 1 ./ (1+(5*xi).^2);    % Runge function

tic                         % p is the polynomial of degree (n-1)
cvx_begin                   % minimize the distance in all points
    variable p(n);
    minimize( max(abs(polyval(p, xi) - ri)) );
cvx_end
toc_or = toc                % 0.17 sec for Matlab, CVX and SeDuMi

% Extract a Chebfun from the result
x = chebfun( [-1,1] );
A = [ chebfun(1) , x ];
for k=3:n, A(:,k) = A(:,k-1).*x; end
or = A * flipud(p)

% Make a chebfun of Runge's function
f = chebfun( @(x) 1 ./ ( 1 + 25*x.^2 ) )

% Get the best approximation using Remez
tic, cr = remez( f , 10 ); toc_cr = toc

% Get the maximum error in each case
fprintf( 'maximum error of convex optimization: %e (%f s)\n' , norm( f - or , inf ) , toc_or );
fprintf( 'maximum error of chebfun remez: %e (%f s)\n' , norm( f - cr , inf ) , toc_cr );

% Plot the two error curves
plot( [ f - cr , f - or ] );
legend( 'chebfun remez' , 'convex optimization' );
```

After a lot of output, I get, on my laptop with Matlab 2012a, CVX version 1.22 and Chebfun's latest SVN Snapshot:

```
maximum error of convex optimization: 6.665479e-02 (0.138933 s)
maximum error of chebfun remez: 6.592293e-02 (0.309443 s)
```

Note that the Chebfun `f` used to measure the error is accurate to 15 digits. So Chebfun's Remez takes twice as long, but gets a smaller global error. It should be pointed out that CVX uses compiled code for the optimization whereas Chebfun is 100% native Matlab. The minimum error of `0.00654` is the minimum error 'on the grid', off that grid, the error can be up to `0.00659`. Increasing the grid size to `m = 1001` I get

```
maximum error of convex optimization: 6.594361e-02 (0.272887 s)
maximum error of chebfun remez: 6.592293e-02 (0.319717 s)
```

i.e. almost the same speed, but the discrete optimization is still worse as of the fourth decimal digit. Finally, ncreasing the grid size further to `m = 10001` I get

```
maximum error of convex optimization: 6.592300e-02 (5.177657 s)
maximum error of chebfun remez: 6.592293e-02 (0.312316 s)
```

i.e. the discrete optimization is now more than ten times slower and is still worse as of the sixth digit.

The bottom line is that Remez will get you the globally optimal result. While the discrete analog may be fast on small grids, it will not give a correct result.

Comment: And N. Trefethen was stressing the same and gave a similar example in the article I was citing. The question was _not_ about the best approximation, but : **What is the advantage of the Remez algorithm** (nowadays) **if you can get the same result with a reasonable convex solver**?

Comment: @HansWerner, I'm sorry, I misread your question. Your convex solver is not giving you the same result, at least not to all digits. If I understand your convex code correctly, you're minimizing the maximum error over a discrete set of points. This is a good approximation of -- but not the same as -- minimizing the global maximum error.

Comment: The convex solver in this case gave a _better_ result. Think of it, the Remez algorithm is an iterative procedure, quite similar to an optimization routine, and will not return an exact result, too. In the concrete case above, the solution from the optimization was better, i.e. had an overall smaller maximum norm, than the result from the best Remez implementation I know. **The question is still open**.

Comment: @HansWerner, how did you measure the maximum error of the solution obtained with the convex solver? The Remez algorithm in `chebfun` should iterate until the minimum is achieved to machine precision (in a sense).

Comment: Not necessarily; there are options like 'tol' (which is relative tolerance) or 'maxiter' for `chebfun/remez`, but there are similar options for all kinds of optimization solvers. In a way one could say, Remez is an optimization routine specialized for a certain task. And the question is: Have the general purpose solvers caught up and there is no need anymore for such a specialized solver? Of course, I may be wrong.

Comment: @HansWerner, again, how did you measure the maximum error of the solution obtained with the convex solver? Did you use the discrete measure as in your example? If so, then the solution from the convex solver is probably 'not' optimal and has a maximum off of the grid you used which is larger than the global maximum in the polynomial generated by `chebfun`.

Comment: No, I did compute the difference between curves through a 1-dim. optimization routine. I am not new on the block, and you are free to check all the calculations yourself. Let's stop here, Pedro, and give others a chance to step in.

Comment: @HansWerner, I would be very happy to check all the calculations, however, could you please add the verification code to your question? Many thanks.